# Install GRASS Addon within QGIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I want to install some GRASS-Addons to use them in QGIS. 
Therefore I run GRASS-Plugin in QGIS an open the GRASS-Shell
type: g.extension

GRASS opens
then i go to "optional", activate "System installation" and type the extensionname "r.viewshed.cva"

after this I run the whole thing and get the following output:

(Tue Nov 05 15:53:05 2013)
g.extension -s extension=r.viewshed.cva svnurl=http://svn.osgeo.org/grass/grass-addons/grass6
which: wget: unknown command
WARNING: GRASS_ADDON_PATH is not defined, installing to ~/.grass6/addons/
Fetching  from GRASS-Addons SVN (be patient)...
A    r.viewshed.cva\description.html
A    r.viewshed.cva\Makefile
A    r.viewshed.cva\r.viewshed.cva.py
Checked out revision 58151.
Compiling ...
C:/OSGeo4W/apps/grass/GRASS-~1.3/include/Make/Grass.make:423
: warning: overriding commands for target
`C:\Users\Warsow\.grass6/1/addons/.tmp/1084.0/dist.i686-pc-
msys/bin'
C:/OSGeo4W/apps/grass/GRASS-~1.3/include/Make/Grass.make:414
: warning: ignoring old commands for target`
C:\Users\Warsow.grass6/1/addons/.tmp/1084.0/dist.i686-pc-
msys/bin'
make: C:\Users\Warsow.grass6/1/addons/.tmp/1084.0/dist.i686
-pc-msys/tools/g.echo.exe: Command not found
make: C:\Users\Warsow.grass6/1/addons/.tmp/1084.0/dist.i686
-pc-msys/tools/g.echo.exe: Command not found
mkdir -p C:\Users\Warsow.grass6/1/addons/.tmp/1084.0/dist.i686-pc-msys/bin
mkdir -p C:\Users\Warsow.grass6/1/addons/.tmp/1084.0/dist.i686-pc-msys/include/grass
mkdir -p C:\Users\Warsow.grass6/1/addons/.tmp/1084.0/dist.i686-pc-msys/etc
mkdir -p C:\Users\Warsow.grass6/1/addons/.tmp/1084.0/dist.i686-pc-msys/driver
mkdir -p C:\Users\Warsow.grass6/1/addons/.tmp/1084.0/dist.i686-pc-msys/driver/db
mkdir -p C:\Users\Warsow.grass6/1/addons/.tmp/1084.0/dist.i686-pc-msys/fonts
make: *** No rule to make target `r.viweshed.cva.py', needed
by`C:\Users\Warsow.grass6/1/addons/.tmp/1084.0/dist.i686
-pc-msys/scripts/r.viweshed.cva.py'.  Stop.
ERROR: Compilation failed, sorry. Please check above error messages.
rm: cannot remove directory `C:\Users\Warsow\.grass6/1/ad
dons/.tmp/1084.0/r.viewshed.cva': Permission denied
(Tue Nov 05 15:53:12 2013) Command finished (7 sec)

I don't know why it doesn't work - could somebody help me?

Win 7
QGIS 2.0
GRASS 6.4.3

Answer (score 4):

The solution is given in the [r.viewshed.cva.py](http://svn.osgeo.org/grass/grass-addons/grass6/raster/r.viewshed.cva/r.viewshed.cva.py)

It is a Python script and the line 189 is:

```
 grass.run_command("r.viewshed",....
```

So you need to install [r.vieshed](http://svn.osgeo.org/grass/grass-addons/grass6/raster/r.viewshed/) first but most Windows computers don't have a common compiler and a building environment built.
The developers compile every night the addon modules for Windows (see [Installing an addon in winGRASS 7.0 for complete dummy](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Installing-an-addon-in-winGRASS-7-0-for-complete-dummy-td5049244.html#a5087468) , it is the same for GRASS GIS 6.4.3). They are in [Win GRASS 6.4.3 addons](http://wingrass.fsv.cvut.cz/grass64/addons/grass-6.4.3/)

If you don't want to use g.extension, download [r.viewshed.zip](http://wingrass.fsv.cvut.cz/grass64/addons/grass-6.4.3/r.viewshed.zip) and [r.viewshed.cva.zip](http://wingrass.fsv.cvut.cz/grass64/addons/grass-6.4.3/r.viewshed.cva.zip), an unzip in your GRASS_ADDON_PATH (C:\Users\Warsow.grass6/1/addons/? from your output)