# command r.stream.order not found in grass 7.0.3 how to install r.stream module?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, osgeo4w, grass-7.0

I have installed QGIS 2.14.1 and GrassGIS 7.0.3

I found in OSGEO Grass wiki page a command that calculate Strahler's and Horton's stream order Hack's main streams and Shreeve's stream magnitude from a drainage, that command is r.stream.order  but when I tried to use it I don't found the command only have r.stream.extrac.

¿Anyone know how to install the other commands or the complete module?

I install QGIS and GrassGIS from the OSGEO installer osgeo4w.setup-x86_64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Various r.stream.* modules must be installed as addons with g.extension. This must be done in GRASS explicitly, because g.extension seems not available via QGIS.

see for details: https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/AddOns/GRASS7/raster

This works fine for GRASS7 as a standalone application.

**edit/add:**

... but might not really solve your issue, but this might help 
too:

[How to make GRASS 7 addon available in QGIS 2.12?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172263/how-to-make-grass-7-addon-available-in-qgis-2-12)

[install GRASS Addon in with QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76514/install-grass-addon-in-with-qgis)

http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/Adding_New_Tools_to_the_GRASS_Toolbox