# Installing a GRASS addon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-grass-plugin

I am trying to use the GRASS addon `r.vector.ruggedness` in QGIS, but it is not available. Then, I downloaded GRASS directly and there it is possible to download the addon that I want. Nevertheless, I have never used GRASS and I am trying to understand how it works but it is not very straightforward for me. Then, I would like to know if there is some way in which I could install a GRASS addon (in this case `r.vector.ruggedness`) in QGIS.

I understand that you could compute VRM through SAGA, but I trust more in GRASS.

I found a similar question from some time ago, available in this [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76514/install-grass-addon-within-qgis), but I didn't find it very helpful.

I am using QGIS 3.22.3.

Comment: Which operating system do you use and which GRASS GIS version?
The module is here: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/addons/r.vector.ruggedness.html

Comment: I am using Windows. I know that the latest version of GRASS is 8.0, but when I download QGIS 3.22.3, it comes with GRASS GIS 7.8.6. 
The VRM is available in GRASS, but not in the GRASS plugin in QGIS. So I don't know if there is some way to install that module in the GRASS plugin of QGIS.

Comment: You may use the OSGeo4W installer: https://grass.osgeo.org/download/windows/#OSGeo4W --> "Download OSGeo4W v2" which let's you install both QGIS and GRASS GIS (and more).